# "Port" package to a new name npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to port my package to a new name, however, I want to keep all releases when that happens, and not just the latest release. I have a couple questions:

- Can you port all releases to a new name,
- Can you "redirect" the old package name to the new package.